# MALLET Topic Modeling: input String

Tags: java, topic-modeling, mallet

I have this code to import a file .mallet:

```
File f=new File("/home/test/file.mallet");
InstanceList t=InstanceList.load(f);
```

but if I wanted to switch manually every single instance, how could I do? 
I tried this:

```
String str="Test for mallet.";
InstanceList t=new InstanceList();
t.add(new Instance(str,"test","test",null));
```

But it gives me an error!

**EDIT**

I tried it and it seems to work with an array of strings:

```
ArrayList<String> aa =ArrayList<Pipe>();
aa.add("Test string 1.");
aa.add("Test string 2.");

String[] ob1=new String[aa.size];
ob1=aa.toArray(ob1);

ArrayList<Pipe> pipeList=ArrayList<Pipe>();
pipeList.add(new CharSequenceLowerCase());
//....
pipeList.add(new TokenSequence2FeatureSequence());

InstanceList training=new InstanceList(new SerialPipes(pipeList))

training.addThruPipe(new StringArrayIterator(ob1));
```

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Usually it is passed to a file .mallet for topic modeling , if you want to pass a string as in the second example?

Comment: I would post your edition as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a list of strings or objects instead of a file for Mallet, you have to use an iterator for the thrupipe. Depending on the type of objects you want to use you can either use a [StringArrayIterator](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/api/cc/mallet/pipe/iterator/StringArrayIterator.html) or simply an [ArrayIterator](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/api/cc/mallet/pipe/iterator/ArrayIterator.html). The StringArrayIterator expects an array of strings, the ArrayIterator expects either a list or an array of objects. API is not that well documented but is straight forward to use.

```
ArrayList<Pipe> pipeList = new ArrayList<>();
pipeList.add(new CharSequenceLowercase());
pipeList.add(new CharSequence2TokenSequence(Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}\\p{N}_]+")));
pipeList.add(new TokenSequenceRemoveStopwords(false, false));
...

InstanceList instances = new InstanceList(new SerialPipes(pipeList));
```

Choose either to use an array or list of objects:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("text1 text2 text3");
list.add("text4 text5");
list.add("text6 text7");
instances.addThruPipe(new ArrayIterator(list));
```

Or an array of strings:

```
String[] array = new String[]{"text1","text2","text3"};
instances.addThruPipe(new StringArrayIterator(array));
```

Part of the example is taken from [here](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/import-devel.php).